# SQL to Arduino via C♯

Tags: c#, mysql, arduino

As part of a project I'm putting together, I have an Arduino updating a MySQL database via C♯ and, in another location I have another C♯ program doing a simple SELECT query on the database, and communicating its findings to another Arduino via Serial. I have written most of the code for this second program but am having some annoying issues at the end of it all.

Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string hkday;
            string hkall;
            //SERIAL
            SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.NewLine = "\n";

            //OPEN SERIAL
            serialPort1.Open();

            //SQL
            string connString = "Server=xxxx;Uid=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Port=xxxx;Database=xxxx;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            MySqlCommand command1 = conn.CreateCommand();
            command1.CommandText = "Select USERS from HK where UPTIME='HKDAY'";
            MySqlCommand command2 = conn.CreateCommand();
            command2.CommandText = "Select USERS from HK where UPTIME='HKALL'";

            //EXECUTE QUERIES
            if (_continue = true)
            {
                conn.Open(); //Connect
                MySqlDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader1.Read())
                {
                    //Write to value and string   
                    Console.WriteLine(reader1["USERS"].ToString());
                    hkday = reader1["USERS"].ToString();
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
                _continue = false;
                conn.Close(); //Disconnect
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Open(); //Connect
                MySqlDataReader reader2 = command1.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    //Write to console and string    
                    Console.WriteLine(reader2["USERS"].ToString());
                }
                hkall = reader2["USERS"].ToString();

                Console.ReadLine();
                _continue = true;
                conn.Close(); //Disconnect

                //WRITE STRINGS TO SERIAL
                serialPort1.WriteLine(
                    String.Format(hkday, hkall));
            }

            serialPort1.Close();

        }

        public static bool _continue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

1. I can't work out how my section titled WRITE STRINGS TO SERIAL needs to be syntaxed and placed within the code to be able to reference both 'hkday' and 'hkall'
2. My 'if (_continue = true)' flag doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why.
3. I think that if these two issues are solved, the program ought to work, can you see any other glaring issues?

Thank you, I know these are only tiny issues, but I can't seem to work them out.

Potentially important: I'm trying to get the output as '123,456\n' as my arduino program already recognises this as its input.

---

### UPDATE

Having received the answers I have, I have compounded this project with the other one I'm currently doing to try and have an arduino update a MySQL database via C# and then also have it download the table's data that it isn't updating to display out through another arduino.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace SQL_Scraper
{

    public partial class Sandro : Form
    {
        //Serial Settings
        SerialPort UNO = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
        SerialPort MEGA = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);

        //Incoming Data String
        string RxString;

        //Int for download
        int? vnday = 0;
        int? vnall = 0;

        public Sandro()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Open UNO port
            UNO.Open();

            //Open MEGA Port
            MEGA.Open();
        }

        private void MEGA_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Sandro_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (UNO.IsOpen | MEGA.IsOpen)
            {
                UNO.Close();
                MEGA.Close();
            }
        }

        private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Begin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Turn off start button
            Begin.Enabled = false;
            //?
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
            //Create Event Handler if data is receiverd
            MEGA.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(MEGA_DataReceived);

            string SQLString = "Server=benchmarkcount.db.9506323.hostedresource.com;Uid=benchmarkcount;Password=Watercress2428;Port=3306;Database=benchmarkcount;";
            MySqlConnection SQLConnection = new MySqlConnection(SQLString);

            //Receive data
            RxString = MEGA.ReadExisting();

            //Append Serial Input to Output box)
            outputBox.AppendText(RxString);

            //Get Unsaved input from text box
            string input = outputBox.Text;
            string[] inputLines = input.Split('\n');

            //Upload findings from MEGA to SQL
            foreach (string line in inputLines)
            {
                if (line.EndsWith("\r")) //Makes sure line is complete
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("Today's total users: "))
                    {
                        string dayUsers = line.Substring(20).Trim();
                        MySqlCommand UpdateHKDAY = SQLConnection.CreateCommand();
                        UpdateHKDAY.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", dayUsers);
                        UpdateHKDAY.CommandText = "UPDATE HK SET USERS=?param1 WHERE UPTIME='HKDAY'";
                        SQLConnection.Open();
                        UpdateHKDAY.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        SQLConnection.Close();
                    }
                    else if (line.StartsWith("All-time total users: "))
                    {
                        string allUsers = line.Substring(21).Trim();
                        MySqlCommand UpdateHKALL = SQLConnection.CreateCommand();
                        UpdateHKALL.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", allUsers);
                        UpdateHKALL.CommandText = "UPDATE HK SET USERS=?param2 WHERE UPTIME='HKALL'";
                        SQLConnection.Open();
                        UpdateHKALL.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        SQLConnection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Only keep unparsed text in text box
            outputBox.Text = inputLines[inputLines.Length - 1];

            //Download Numbers Query
            MySqlCommand DownUsers = new MySqlCommand("Select USERS, UPTIME from VN where UPTIME IN ('VNDAY', 'VNALL')", SQLConnection);

            //Open Connection
            SQLConnection.Open();

            //Execute Downloading Numbers
            MySqlDataReader theResults = DownUsers.ExecuteReader();
            while (theResults.Read())
            {
                switch (theResults["UPTIME"] as string)
                {
                    case "VNDAY":
                        vnday = theResults["USERS"] as int?;
                        break;
                    case "VNALL":
                        vnall = theResults["USERS"] as int?;
                        break;
                }
            }

            //Do things with the results
            UNO.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1}", vnday, vnall));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1}", vnday, vnall));

            //Close Connection
            SQLConnection.Close();
        }

        private void Sandro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Cease_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Begin.Enabled = true;
            Cease.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would like to be able to check this data - the data being sent to the arduino - in my inputBox to make sure it's in the format "vnday, vnall\n"

Comment: What is the point of your _continue flag? Are you trying to alternate between HKDAY and HKALL each time you run the program? Also, the String.Format(hkday, hkall) suggests that hkday is a format string. Is it? Or are you trying to read two values in one run and output them sequentially in specific format? If so, why the flag at all?

Comment: The _continue flag I put there, because the connection needs to be closed after each SQL Select, apparently. If it tries to do to two queries in one go, it says that the connection needs to be opened but is already open. This way, I create a sort of false separation where the connection can be opened and closed on each query, and the code iterates between the two queries repeatedly. Is it more sensible to rewrite the query to include both parts and have it all happen in one connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and example has too many contradictions. It appears that you are under impression that there is static persistence between separate app runs. There isn't. All your static variables will be cleared with each run. It would be different if you had a method that you called in a loop inside the same app domain.

Also, judging by your variable names and your output requirement, the USERS field is a numeric.

So, assuming you have following table:

```
USERS    UPTIME
------   ------
123456   HKALL
234567   HKDAY
```

following code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int? hkday = 0;
    int? hkall = 0;

    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("..."))
    {
        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select USERS, UPTIME from HK where UPTIME IN ('HKDAY', 'HKALL')", conn);

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //this assumes that there is only one record per 'HKDAY' and 'HKALL',
        //otherwise the last value will be stored
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader["UPTIME"] as string)
            {
                case "HKDAY":
                    hkday = reader["USERS"] as int?;
                    break;
                case "HKALL":
                    hkall = reader["USERS"] as int?;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:N0}\n{1:N0}\n", hkday, hkall));
}
```

will output:

```
234,567
123,456
```

Or if you desire to run independent queries:

```
private static int? GetUSERS(string hkval)
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("..."))
    {
        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select USERS from HK where UPTIME=@hkval", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("hkval", hkval);

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
            return reader["USERS"] as int?;

        return null;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    int hkday = (int)GetUSERS("HKDAY");
    int hkall = (int)GetUSERS("HKALL");

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:N0}\n{1:N0}\n", hkday, hkall));
}
```

You could also pass HKDAY/HKALL as a parameter to you app using args.

Comment: Ah damn, sorry, I wasn't clear in my asking of the question, the format i want the string in is "hkday, hkall \n" not "hk, day \n hk, all \n" But I'll amend the WriteLine thusly. Is that enough to change it?

Comment: I see. I read 123,456 as one number. Just change it to "{0}, {1}\n". That will produce two numbers separated by a comma and followed by LN character. In my example you'll get "234579, 123456\n".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C programmer but know a lot of serial ports, I suppouse that this solves your first issue.

```
//WRITE STRINGS TO SERIAL
      serialPort1.Write(hkday);             // do not append line feed
      serialPort1.WriteLine(hkall);         // append line feed
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a little more explicit, the problem is that at the //WRITE STRINGS TO SERIAL part of the code, I am unable to use the 'hkday' string because it's not declared in that context; it's in the 'if' part of the statement, so if i instead go to 'else', C# doesn't know what 'hkday' is.